# What is the probability of 3 heart and 2 distinct pairs in a hand of five cards?

Tags: probability, poker

Given that the hand is drawn from a standard deck of 52 cards, what is the probability that it contains three hearts and two distinct pairs?

I know that there are ${52 \choose 5}$ distinct hands of five, and that each pair will contain exactly one heart, with the third heart not being in a pair.

So far, my work is that there are:

${13 \choose 3}$ ways to draw three hearts

${3 \choose 2}$ ways to select which of the two hearts are part of the two pairs

${3\choose2}$ ways to select the suit of the other card for each pair

And so the probability would be $\frac{{13 \choose 3}{3 \choose 2}^3}{{52 \choose 5}}$, about 0.003

I can't help but feel like I am leaving something out, though. Have I forgotten to include anything in the numerator?

Comment: Does a "distinct pair" rule out three of a kind (full house-one pair and then three of another)?

Comment: "${3 \choose 2}$ ways to select the suit of the other card for each pair"  That's not correct.  You have ${3\choose 1}$ way to choose one of the suits and ${3\choose 1}$ way to chose the other.

Comment: Hmm.... no I'm mistaken. Brain fart.  YOu *DID* square it.  Sorry.

Comment: Well, it *should* be ${3\choose 1}$ and not ${3 \choose 2}$ for the other suit of each pair but as ${3\choose 1} = {3\choose 2}$ .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This becomes easy once you realize that a pair can't be *both* hearts.  So at most each pair accounts for one heart and the fifth card must be the third.  SO the only way you can have two pairs and three hearts is to have a pair with one of the cards a heart, another pair and one of the cards a heart, and the fifth card a heart.

There are there are ${13 \choose 2}$ possible options the pairs can be.  there are $11$ options the fifth card can be.  For each pair there are $3$ options the second card in the pair can be.

So there are ${13\choose 2}\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 11=$

$\frac {13\cdot 12}2\cdot 99 = 13\cdot 6\cdot 99 = 7722$ ways to do this.

So probality is $\frac {\frac {13!}{11!2!}9*11}{\frac {52!}{47!5!}} =\frac {7722}{2598960} \approx 0.003$

Which is the same answer as yours as I did $ {13\choose 2}\cdot{{13-2} \choose 1}=\frac {13!}{11!2!}\frac {11!}{10!1!}$ whereas you did ${13\choose 3}{3\choose 1}=\frac {13!}{10!3!}\frac {3!}{2!1!}$ which are clearly the same value.  (there's probably a combinatorial argument why).